# How center data on label

Tags: label, center, zpl

Hello I want center data on my label.

My label is 95 mm x 25mm

I tried center useing ^FB and C to center but nothing happend.

Below please see my code in ZPL:

I need to center :

```
`^FT429,220^A0B,25,24^FH\^FDMade in Poland^FS`

`^FT400,225^A0B,25,24^FH\^FD{:DrawingDate}^FS`
`^FT309,257^A0B,25,24^FH\^FD{:PartDescription}^FS`
`^FT274,295^A0B,33,33^FH\^FD{:CustomerPartNumber}^FS`
`^FT872,231^A0B,25,24^FH\^FD{:PartNumber}^FS` 

`^FT915,198^A0B,25,24^FH\^FD{:Date}^FS`

`^FT364,276^A0B,33,33^FH\^FD{:DrawingNumber}^FS`
```

What and where I need change my code to center on label my data?

Answer (score 1):

without seeing the expected label it is difficult work on your given requirement.for a 4x1 label the following code does print with "centre" alignment.

```
^XA
^CF0,30,30^FO25,50
^A0N,25,24
^FB750,10,,C
^FDMade in Poland\&
{:DrawingDate} \&
{:PartDescription}  \&
{:CustomerPartNumber} \&
{:PartNumber} \&
{:Date} \&
{:DrawingNumber} \&
^FS
^XZ
```

label output:
[image]